# I'm trying to solve for a stopping time given a distance. Think I have the answer.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Trying to work with grouping variables and eliminating the exponent. Please help by explaining how you come to a different answer.

The equation is $870t=16t^2$

My logic is to divide $t$ from both sides to get $870$ by itself: $870=16t^2/t$

Then by expanding the right side, the equation should look like: $870=16\times t\times t/t$

Can't the $t/t$ be simplified to $1$?: $870=16\times t\times 1$

Combining like terms $16\times 1$ is $16$ so: $870=16t$

Then divide by $16$ on both sides: $870/16=t$

So, shouldn't $t=54.375$?  My workbook says no, please help.

Does $t=54.375$?

**Edit:** You guys are great, thanks so much! Here's the original question:

The following formula relates the distance *s* (in feet) traveled by a vehicle during an emergency stop to the time *t* (in seconds) it takes to arrive at a complete stop: *s(t)=16t^2*.

At the scene of an accident, Bill uses skid marks to determine the braking distance of one of the vehicles involved was about 870 feet.

What is the corresponding braking time?

Comment: Notice that when $t=0$, the equation is true, $0=0$. Do not divide with a variable without going trough the case seperately.

Comment: $t=0$ is one solution; the other solution is exactly the solution you have given. Note that your methodology does not work if $t=0$ since you cannot divide by $0$.

Comment: what you did was fine and your answer is correct - the book must be wrong ( unless there is something you didn't tell us)

Comment: Can you post the original question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you accelerate from a stop or decelerate to a stop in time $t$ at acceleration $a$, the distance covered is $s=\frac 12at^2$, so they are taking $a=32$, which assumes the car can decelerate at one gravity.  The units are ft/sec^2. As the skid marks are $870$ feet, your equation should be $870=16t^2$

Comment: Thank you for the help on this. It looks like the answer was the square root of 870/16. What I don't get is what happened to the 't' on the left of the equation?

Comment: There shouldn't be one.  The distance covered is $16t^2$ and you are given that it is $870$ feet.  Your units do not match, as $870t$ is feet-seconds.